# jQuery scrollTop and parallax effect: Browser window jitters when scrolling at the very bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, parallax, scrolltop

I have a little script that is creating a parallax effect. Therefore I created a data attribute with the speed velocity and a data-type to select the parallax elements. At the very same time, one of the elements fades out when scrolling down.

The script works fine, but unfortunately, when scrolling to the bottom of the site (and "overscroll" it), the site jitters like hell. It seems to be the part with the yPos and scrollTop method.

Do you have any ideas what the problem is?

**Here's the markup:**

```
<section class="slider">
  <img src="images/hafen.jpg" class="slide" data-type="parallax" data-speed="3">
  <div class="claim"  data-type="parallax" data-speed="6">
    <h1>SOME TEXT</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-down" data-type="parallax" data-speed="3">
    <img src="images/arrow-down.png" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
<section class="content"  data-type="parallax" data-speed="1">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="images/content.png" alt="">
  </div>
<section>
```

**That's my script:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var box;
  $("[data-type=\"parallax\"]").each(function() {
    var $bgobj, position, yPos;
    $bgobj = $(this);
    yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data("speed"));
    position = parseInt(yPos);
    return $bgobj.css({
      marginTop: position
    });
  });
  box = $(".claim");
  return box.css({
    "opacity": 1 - $window.scrollTop() / 400
  });
});
```

Comment: Your lasy section tag is not properly closed. Can you check with this corrected?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing `(` and `)` around `window` here:

```
yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data("speed"));
```

Should be:

```
yPos = -($(window).scrollTop() / $bgobj.data("speed"));
```

And you `<section>` isn't closed at the very end. Should be:

```
...
</section>
```

Not sure what your expected result should look like with proper CSS, but this seems to be working with the above changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Zmh8/

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var box;
        $("[data-type=\"parallax\"]").each(function () {
            var $bgobj, position, yPos;
            $bgobj = $(this);
            yPos = -($(window).scrollTop() / $bgobj.data("speed"));
            position = parseInt(yPos);
            return $bgobj.css({
                marginTop: position
            });
        });
        box = $(".claim");
        return box.css({
            "opacity": 1 - $window.scrollTop() / 400
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for that! I closed the <section>. My window object had a global variable $window = $(window) before that I didn't post. sorry for that. nothing changed :-/

Comment: Could you set up your non-working case in http://jsfiddle.net like I did above, so that we can look at it there?